# How can I go back to the previous page on ASP.Net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

Imagine I have a button which has " `OnClick="GoBack"` " I want it to go to the previous page, how will C# function code look like?

Comment: The right answer was:

`static string prevPage = String.Empty;

 prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

 Response.Redirect(prevPage);`


By the way thank you so much for your useless answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["RefUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    }
}

protected void GoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object refUrl = ViewState["RefUrl"];
    if (refUrl != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect((string)refUrl);
    }
}
```